# my asp:menu control is hidden when it contains no items - how can I show it?

Tags: asp.net, css

I added an asp:menu control (with a web.sitemap backend) to my app.  For this particular app, when the user is not logged in, I don't want to show any menu items, but I do want the menu to have the same color as the bitmap header under it.  However, when the menu is empty, I just end up with a blank rectangle.  It's a static menu, 5 items, using CSS to style it.  I've tried adding the background color to the menu, the staticmenu style, and the staticmenuitem style with no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap the menu control in a `div` to create a container that will always exist regardless and give it a background color?

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why I didn't think of that